# How to perform mass update using eloquent?

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-5

I have a model `Post` and want to bulk-update it's records. I'm aware of this method:

```php
Post::where('id', '>', '10')->update(...)
```

But I need to **increment** the `times_seen` property of the records. In other words, I need to increase the value of `times_seen` property by 1, for each record matching a `where(...)` conditional. For example:

```php
Post::where('id', '>', '10')->update(['times_seen', ?]) // '?' = 'times_seen + 1'
```

How should I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the **increment()** method of the query builder:

```php
Post::where('id', '>', 10)->increment('times_seen');
```

If you need to increment it by more than one, you can pass the exact value as second parameter:

```php
Post::where('id', '>', 10)->increment('times_seen', 5);
```